# Unable to Centre Advert In CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to centre a div in CSS, but it fails to centre. 
I've tried adding `text-align: center;` to no avail.

The link to the issue is https://www.fir3net.com/ and it is the top advert.

Any ideas?

Sample Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="uk-panel uk-text-center topadvert">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.topadvert {
    width:728px;
    height:90px
}
```

Comment: You should include relevant code in your question - not just an external link, especially since the link may become invalid in the future.

Comment: you have many answers now... does any of these help??? please accept the answer for future references... and add the relevant code as suggested by Dan!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `.topadvert` class

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

You don't need `text-align:center` on the containing div, you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a block element, `text-align` works on inline elements.

You want `margin: 0 auto;`

[text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)
[margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values)

Comment: text-align works on a div, but it affects inline content of the div, not the position of the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

** updated the inline code in the class being used

Add below CSS to "`<div class="uk-panel uk-text-center **topadvert**">` " :

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Below is the code

```
.topadvert {
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto; /*ADDED*/
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Save this image and open for better clarity!!]

Save this image and open for better clarity!!

### Fiddle for the same > http://jsfiddle.net/azt9Lnem/1/

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/azt9Lnem/2/embedded/result/)

Hope this will help!!!